# How to calculate different result when condition (x < 10)

Tags: assembly, mips

So I am given a task to create program using Assembly, that ask the user for a number *x*.

If the *x* is less than 10, it substitutes (x*2) into x of (x-7)+(x%3) and print out the result.

If its greater than 10, then it just uses the equation
(x-7)+(x%3).

So far I have done everything for the second part "(x-7)+(x%3)".

I need help figuring out how to find if x < 10 and how to switch to that equation.

```
     .data
Q1:  .asciiz "Enter an integer x: "
op1: .asciiz "(x - 7) + (x % 3) = "
op2: .asciiz "((x * 2) - 7) + ((x * 2) % 3) = "

.text

    #Get x from user
    la  $a0, Q1     #Load the prompt
    li  $v0, 4      #Print the question for the user
    syscall
    li  $v0, 5      #Get x from the user
    syscall
    move    $t0, $v0    #Save x in reg $t0

    #Determine if x is less than 10
    #TODO not implemented

    #Performing the calculations
    sub $t1, $t0, 7 #t1 = (x - 7)
    rem $t2, $t0, 3 #t2 = (x % 3)
    add $t3, $t1, $t2   #t3 = (x - 7) + (x % 3)

    #Output results for x > 10
    la  $a0, op1
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall
    move    $a0, $t3
    li  $v0, 1
    syscall


    #End the program
halt:   li  $v0, 10
        syscall
```

Answer (score 2):

From the `syscall` usage it looks like you are using one of MARS/SPIM MIPS simulators. If you happen to use MARS, the mere <kbd>F1</kbd> will bring you help window, where you can click on tabs with various information, including full list of basic and supported pseudo instructions. When thinking about some algorithm/task, use several rounds of thinking how to break the task down into algorithm and into simple steps, and checking the instruction set to see which instructions are available.

At the point of the comment in code you have user value as integer in `t0` and you need to multiply it by two, if it is less than 10. The remaining calculation is same for both cases, so in C you can do:

```
    if (x < 10) x *= 2;
    // continue with "(x - 7) + (x % 3) = " calculation
```

And you let the optimizer of compiler to beat the sh*t out of it. If you would create a major copy/paste spaghetti code like: `if (x < 10) { ...formulae with x*2 code... } else { ...same formulae with simple x code...}`, you have still a very decent chance, that modern compiler will notice it and reduce it to single calculation with `x` or `x*2` value depending on condition.

In assembly you are also the optimizer, so let's try some more (after you realize that you can reuse the same calculation for both cases).

The `integer x *= 2` can be done in assembly by shifting value left by one bit, which is much faster and simpler operation for CPU, than calculating full multiplication (It's like for humans doing *10 on paper, you can either calculate it by regular multiplication of two values, or you can just add "0" at the end of source number ... in binary the shift left adds zero bits at end).

And the `if` means branching, but branching is generally ineffective for CPU. If it can be reasonably avoided, avoid it.

In your case, when the condition is true, you need to shift by 1 bit left. When the condition is false, you need to keep original value of x intact. But that is equal to "shift left by zero bits". Now if you will turn the condition into 1/0 result, you may shift-left x by such result to achieve what you need.

If you will check instructions for "less than" variants, and "left shift" variants - to see what are your options and what is directly supported by CPU - you may notice you can resolve this task with two instructions only, it's like the MIPS was almost built for your task:

```
    # set t1 to value 0 or 1, depending on the (x < 10) condition
    slti  $t1, $t0, 10   # t1 = 1 when x < 10 || 0 when 10 <= x
    # now use the 1/0 value to adjust x by left-shifting it
    sllv  $t0, $t0, $t1  # shift left x by t1 bits (doing *= 2 or *= 1)
```

Done.

If the task was supposed to make you practice branching, check internet for some MARS/SPIM tutorial about branching, and practice on it, don't ruin this particular task by such inefficiency.

Comment: Fun fact: gcc5.4 needs hand-holding (`x <<= (x<10);`) to use slt / variable-shift on MIPS, unless you use `-march=mips32` (or something like `mips4` or newer).  Maybe generic MIPS had slow variable-shift instructions?  https://godbolt.org/g/7UJNKn.  And it fails to take advantage of the branch-delay slot with an `li` that it's going to need :/

Comment: @PeterCordes wtf is `cmovb   edi, eax` `mov     eax, edi` ??? :D is it "movs are now so cheap that it doesn't matter to add one more redundant" or doest the `cmovnb` not exist, or what was the gcc 7.2 thinking? :D  ... and if-else variant with two formulae gets compiled as two code branches, but that's probably correct due to the extreme cases... no, it's not, unsigned int < 10 will end as 0..18 range, even values, so substitution is 100% identical in this particular case. The optimizer probably doesn't care as much about math as I imagined. Makes sense, just for my information, thanks. :)

Comment: I take it back, with -Os the two return variant is recognized and merged into single code path. So it just doesn't care about code size with -O3 that much, and single jcc looks performant enough.

Comment: Yup, looks like you spotted a missed optimization; `cmovnb` would be strictly better than `cmovb`/`mov`.  Report it as a "missed-optimization" bug in gcc if you want; it costs an extra uop (and since it does this even without `-march=haswell`) it costs an extra cycle of latency on the critical path on CPUs where integer `mov` has non-zero latency.  Wasted `mov` instructions are unfortunately not rare from most compilers. Most people who says that compilers are amazing and fantastic and always do a great job haven't looked carefully at compiler output. They almost always do a *good* job, though

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm too lazy to report it. Yeah, I went from "compilers are horrible, hand written assembly is the only way" to "compilers are OK-ish" just recently (~5y back), so I'm personally nowhere near "compilers are amazing"... Still if I would write any usable SW by my own standards, I would start with C++, it's mostly OK. Pity in the commercial world I'm actually forced to deliver horrible abominations, like Java... and as if that is not bad enough itself, they add ton of libraries/abstraction layers with generated hidden code to it. The GHz CPUs came too soon, mankind was not ready. :)

Comment: I have a small amount of optimism about the future of code-bloat.  Single-threaded performance is still increasing, but *much* more slowly than in the past, so there's reason to believe that people might spend some time making code efficient occasionally.  Of course, larger caches are helping bloated code catch up to efficient code outside of inner loops, reducing the incentive in some cases.